# Comparing datetimes in eval to hours

Tags: c#, eval

I've got a datetime and I want to check if there is 24 hours difference between those two. I just don't know how to do that.
So far I've got this:

```
<%#   (DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("new_date"))) < 24 ? "Today" : Eval("new_date") %>
```

It does not work tho :<
@Edit
And this is how datetime in my database looks like for example:

```
2016-09-18 12:26:14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between 2 `DateTime`s is a `TimeSpan`, which has a `TotalDays` property you could compare to `1.`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It is better to compare to days @_ @

Answer (score 1):

The result oft subtracting two `DateTime` values is a `TimeSpan` which has properties for hours, minutes, etc.

If you've got two `DateTime` values you can check whether the difference between them is less than 24 hours like this:

```
(DateTime.Now - otherDateTime).TotalHours < 24
```

Comment: Thanks good sir, I compared it to days instead It seems like that hours been resetting and it made it to overwrite comparision everytime @_ @

Comment: `Hours` is an integer representing the hours component of the `TimeSpan`, and is always between 0 and 23. A `TimeSpan` representing 26 hours has 1 `Days` and 2 `Hours`. `TotalDays`, `TotalHours`, etc. represent the total `TimeSpan` duration in the appropriate unit.